# Manage SFTP web project on multiple remote web hosts at the same time with Git

Tags: linux, ssh, git, sftp, sublime-text-3

My need would be to figure out if I can do something like this (keeping in mind the answer of @jrtapsell described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1247798/manage-sftp-web-project-on-multiple-remote-web-hosts-at-the-same-time/1247908#comment1831514_1247803)):

1. I would like to install Git directly on the server where I currently host the three versions of the app I am developing (this is a Linux server, where each version is a separate host from the other, so, for example, `/home/develop/public_html` contains the files of develop version the same way as `testing` and `production`)
2. I would like to eliminate, at this point, totally having to use something to execute SFTP upload of files already handled with Git
3. Ideally, therefore, I would like each host to be part of the same Git repository, so I can automatically send the files to each one without needing to upload with SFTP

At this point I wonder: is it possible to work with such a workflow? And, above all, can each host be a portion of the same repository?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Why aren't you already using branches for each version?

Comment: I'm still not very practical about git: branches can certainly work on the same web host (so where all three versions of the software are under the same Linux account, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1247798/manage-sftp-web-project-on-multiple-remote-web-hosts-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but I do not know if it can run on separate hosts (`/home/develop/public_html`, `home/testing/public_html` and `/home/production/public_html`). Is it possible?

Comment: If you need specific code in `/home/{develop|testing|production}/public_html` then you would have a single repository somewhere outside of these three, and something that checks out a given branch and copies it to `/home/{develop|testing|production}/public_html` periodically or on demand (with some continuous integration software you can even have this triggered by a commit to the branch, or you can do it yourself with git hooks on the server)).

Comment: It could be a great solution! Do you have any scripts / software / hook to advise me for periodic checks?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks